# Longtable listed in list of tables indicates different page number than linked to

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable

I have several long tables in appendices which also show up in my list of tables. However, the page number indicated in the table of contents is not the page anchored to when the table name is clicked. For example, I have a longtable that spans pages 71 to 73. The Table of Contents shows the table to be on 73 but when the caption is clicked it links to page 71. I was wondering if anyone had a solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide the compilable document that shows this issue. If the caption is on the top of the `longtable`, the page number should be the one of the starting long table page, not the final one

Comment: probably because unlike `\caption` elsewhere longtable captions do not increment the table counter (that is done by longtable)  try putting \addtocounter{table}{-1} before the longtable, and then in the cell before the caption, do \refstepcounter{table}\label{yourlable}   perhaps.....

Comment: You're a genius, that worked perfectly. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Carlisle had the right solution.

`\addtocounter{table}{-1}` before the longtable and `\refstepcounter{table}\label{mylabel}` worked perfectly.